# Disable Mobile Canvas

Tags: carto

Is it possible to disable the mobile canvas in CartoDB when using the embedded maps?

When I add extra text to a legend and define the the width of it, the legend isn't displayed correctly on the mobile device but looks perfect in desktop mode.

If I don't fix the width the legend takes up way too much space.

[this is my vis](https://omars.cartodb.com/viz/6083fa68-6e7d-11e4-8b4b-0e018d66dc29/map)

Answer (score 1):

By using cartodb.js you can create a visualization and explicitly disable the mobile layout by setting the attribute [mobile_layout](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js.html#cartodbcreatevismapid-vizjsonurl-options--callback) to false. Other thing you can try is to adapt your visualization by configuring the overlays in the [mobile layout editor](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-editor.html#configure-canvas)